# Should the salutation when addressing a principal be 'Dear Principal' or 'Dear Sir'?

Tags: word-choice, letter-writing, salutations

Write a letter to the principal of your school, giving him at least two reasons why he should allow you attend your elder sister's wedding.

Question: Should the salutation be 'Dear Principal' or 'Dear Sir'? Are both salutations correct?

Comment: Hello, Ayoola. Interpersonal Skills.SE is more appropriate for this sort of question (it's a question about preferred interaction styles).

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I'm sympathetic to that comment, but I note that culture and language are inextricably intertwined, so this question is not necessarily off topic here.

Comment: @phoog Lines have to be drawn. If a usage is met with virtually entirely in works / articles on mathematics, the obvious SE site to ask about it is on Mathematics. And this is certainly to do with the etiquette of the language.

Answer (score 5):

I would use *Dear Principal* or *Dear Mr/Dr So-and-So* (you could make up a name). I would only use *Dear Sir* when writing to someone whose name I didn't know (and, of course, you would know the name if it's your school).

Comment: You are saying then that both methods are correct. I share in your sentiment. In fact, I also think that if the principal is a priest, one can say Dear Fr. Principal.

Comment: No, because their name is not Principal.

Comment: @AyoolaIgwe if the principal's name is "John Doe" then _Dear Mr. Doe_ or perhaps _Dear Principal Doe_ depending on the social norms of the place where the school is.  If the principal is a priest then _Dear Fr. Doe._  Whatever the case, _Dear Sir_ is traditionally reserved for someone whose name you do not know.

Comment: @phoog West African Examination Council(WAEC) in its marking scheme approves of 'Dear Sir.' However, I agree with you that Dear Sir is traditionally reserved for someone whose name is unknown.

Comment: @AyoolaIgwe does WAEC specifically approve of "Dear Sir" in cases where the identity of the addressee is known?  I could imagine that it's acceptable in some cultures, where I would sooner characterize it as "old fashioned" than "impersonal."  (In fact, if the addressee's identity is unknown, more recent tradition calls for "Dear Sir or Madam," but I don't know what today's more cautious approach to gender etiquette has to say about that.)

Comment: @phoog typically in a WAEC question, you create context for the letter writing question you are responding to. The marking guide states that where 'Dear Sir' or 'Dear Madam' is used it should be accepted by the examiner.

Comment: So you were really asking "Is my exam board correct in its interpretation?"

Comment: @KateBunting No. I believe the exam body is correct. I was only asking if the other instance I cited is generally acceptable as well in addition to what the exam body, WAEC, that I made reference to provides.